# WPF - I cannot start the app because of the connection exception that i'm getting

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, mvvm

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout
> period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This
> may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max
> pool size was reached.'

I'm trying to add existing username to a collection of errors and I started getting this exception...

I'm getting exception in this class:

```
public class UsersCollection: ObservableCollection<Users>   
{  
    public static UsersCollection GetAllUserNames()
    {
        UsersCollection users = new UsersCollection();
        Users user = null;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();  //I GET EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE.

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName FROM Users", conn);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    user = Users.GetUserNamesFromResultSet(reader);
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

Class with code that causes the exception:

```
public class Users : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private int _id;
    private string _username;
    private string _password;
    private bool _isAdmin;

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            if (_username == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _username = value;

            List<string> errors = new List<string>();
            bool valid = true;

            if (value == null || UserName.Length < 5)
            {
                errors.Add("Username can not have less than 5 characters.");
                SetErrors("UserName", errors);
                valid = false;
            }

            UsersCollection collection = new UsersCollection();  
            collection = UsersCollection.GetAllUserNames();       
                                                                     
            for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)           
            {                                                    
                if (UserName == (object)collection[i])           
                {                                                
                    errors.Add("Username already exist.");       
                    SetErrors("UserName", errors);               
                    valid = false;                               
                }                                                
            }                                                    
            
            if (!Regex.Match(value, @"^\w+$").Success)
            {
                errors.Add("Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscore characters.");
                SetErrors("UserName", errors);
                valid = false;
            }

            if (valid)
            {
                ClearErrors("UserName");
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserName"));
        }

        private void SetErrors(string propertyName, List<string> propertyErrors)
        {
            errors.Remove(propertyName);
            errors.Add(propertyName, propertyErrors);

            if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            {
                ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }    
        }

        private void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            errors.Remove(propertyName);
  
            if (ErrorsChanged != null)
            {
                ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
  
        public static Users GetUserNamesFromResultSet(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            Users user = new Users((string)reader["UserName"]);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

I started receiving exception after i added these lines (I'm not sure if code would do as I wanted, I couldn't test it):

```
UsersCollection collection = new UsersCollection();  
collection = UsersCollection.GetAllUserNames();       
                                                     
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)           
{                                                    
    if (UserName == (object)collection[i])           
    {                                                
        errors.Add("Username already exist.");       
        SetErrors("UserName", errors);               
        valid = false;                               
    }                                                
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Code review comment: What for is `collection = new UsersCollection();` when you reassign it right next line?... What is the point of `UsersCollection: ObservableCollection<Users>` there is no added value with this class (static method can be in any class and returns `ObservableCollection<Users>`... Also there is a Dapper..

Comment: You should prolly dispose sqlcommand, too... If error will be still there the problem could be in other palce... Fx you are not disposing SQLconnection/swlcommands in other places using same connection string

Comment: Also `UserName == (object)collection[i]` doesn't make sens as it is just comparing references because you didn't define equality

Answer (score -1):

what i understood from your question is that you are trying to connect to a pool and from his pool your trying to select a data from users table but sadly you ran into a problem with the pool because its reached max size or limit mmm if you are correct with the connection string try to make cmd.Timeout = 0; there will try reconnect again and again and again until you able to get into the pool.